# No obtengo respuesta de mercado pago desde android studio con java

Tags: java

Estoy integrando mercado pago en mi app desde android studio, aun estoy en la fase de prueba y todo va bien hasta que confirmo el pago y se cuelga, no obtengo ninguna respuesta. Les agrego el codigo que estoy utilizando y funciona bien, el acces_token se lo estoy enviando manualmente por el momento y los demas datos los envio desde la funcion crearJSONDatos().

---

```
public String crearJSONDatos() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("title", "factura");
    json.put("description", "Pago");
    json.put("quantity", 1);
    json.put("currency_id", "ARS");
    json.put("unit_price", 15.00);

    JSONObject jsonObjPayer = new JSONObject();
    jsonObjPayer.put("name", "name");
    jsonObjPayer.put("surname", "sur");
    jsonObjPayer.put("email", "mail@gmail.com");
    jsonObjPayer.put("date_created", "2015-06-02T12:58:41.425-04:00");
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put(json);
    JSONObject datos = new JSONObject();
    datos.put("items", jsonArray);
    datos.put("payer",jsonObjPayer);

    return datos.toString();
}


 private void dbDatosOperacion(String data,String acces_token){
    Log.d("data",data);
    String webServerUrl =
            getResources().getString(R.string.SERVER_URL_API_MP)+acces_token;
    Log.d("web",webServerUrl);
    if (StaticMethods.isNetworkAvailable(getContext())) {
        // OKHTTP
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(StaticMethods.JSON, data);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(webServerUrl)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer Token")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //mostrarError(getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_DE_RED));
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    // Obtiene la respuesta del Web Server
                    final String respuesta = response.body().string();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.d("rta",respuesta);
                                try {
                                    obtenerRespuesta(respuesta);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.d("rta","no");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        //mostrarError(getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_DE_RED));
    }
}

 private void obtenerRespuesta(String respuesta) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(respuesta);
    String id = json.getString("id");
    preference_id = id;
    //Log.d("pre1",preference_id);
    //preference_id = "209768922-e1337db0-4652-42a3-9ba5-540b6df17ff9";
    Log.d("pref",preference_id);
    Log.d("val", String.valueOf(mImpTotal));
    CheckoutPreference checkoutPreference = new CheckoutPreference.Builder()
            .addItem(new Item(preference_id, new BigDecimal(""+mImpTotal+"")))
            .setSite(Sites.ARGENTINA)
            .addExcludedPaymentType(PaymentTypes.TICKET)
            .addExcludedPaymentType(PaymentTypes.ACCOUNT_MONEY)
            .addExcludedPaymentType(PaymentTypes.PREPAID_CARD)
            .setMaxInstallments(48)
            .addExcludedPaymentType(PaymentTypes.BANK_TRANSFER)
            .addExcludedPaymentMethod(PaymentMethods.ARGENTINA.VISA) //Exclude specific payment methods
            .setMaxInstallments(1) //Limit the amount of installments
            .build();

    startMercadoPagoCheckout(checkoutPreference);
}

private void startMercadoPagoCheckout(CheckoutPreference checkoutPreference) {
    new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder()
            .setActivity(getActivity())
            .setPublicKey("TEST-e1438a3e-7acd-4872-9c66-a87677a816a4")
            .setCheckoutPreference(checkoutPreference)
            .startForPayment();
}
```

2020-12-11 12:41:44.881 6792-6792/com.vd.fp D/rta: {"additional_info":"","auto_return":"","back_urls":{"failure":"","pending":"","success":""},"binary_mode":false,"client_id":"5182735662626827","collector_id":209768922,"coupon_code":null,"coupon_labels":null,"date_created":"2020-12-11T15:41:45.236+00:00","date_of_expiration":null,"expiration_date_from":null,"expiration_date_to":null,"expires":false,"external_reference":"","id":"209768922-fe13d4d5-d4b3-4600-b4aa-a100026c9e8e","init_point":"https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/checkout/v1/redirect?pref_id=209768922-fe13d4d5-d4b3-4600-b4aa-a100026c9e8e","internal_metadata":null,"items":[{"id":"","category_id":"","currency_id":"ARS","description":"Pago mediante mercado pago","title":"Pago de factura","quantity":1,"unit_price":15}],"marketplace":"NONE","marketplace_fee":0,"metadata":{},"notification_url":null,"operation_type":"regular_payment","payer":{"phone":{"area_code":"","number":""},"address":{"zip_code":"","street_name":"","street_number":null},"email":"mail@gmail.com","identification":{"number":"","type":""},"name":"name","surname":"surname","date_created":"2015-06-02T12:58:41.425-04:00","last_purchase":null},"payment_methods":{"default_card_id":null,"default_payment_method_id":null,"excluded_payment_methods":[{"id":""}],"excluded_payment_types":[{"id":""}],"installments":null,"default_installments":null},"processing_modes":null,"product_id":null,"redirect_urls":{"failure":"","pending":"","success":""},"sandbox_init_point":"https://sandbox.mercadopago.com.ar/checkout/v1/redirect?pref_id=209768922-fe13d4d5-d4b3-4600-b4aa-a100026c9e8e","site_id":"MLA","shipments":{"default_shipping_method":null,"receiver_address":{"zip_code":"","street_name":"","street_number":null,"floor":"","apartment":"","city_name":null,"state_name":null,"country_name":null}},"total_amount":null,"last_updated":null}
2020-12-11 12:41:44.883 6792-6792/com.vd.fp D/pref: 209768922-fe13d4d5-d4b3-4600-b4aa-a100026c9e8e
2020-12-11 12:41:44.883 6792-6792/com.vd.fp D/val: 1.0
2020-12-11 12:41:44.919 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/es.fp: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)
2020-12-11 12:41:44.950 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:192978491 intent:Intent { cmp=com.viasdigitales.fp/com.mercadopago.CheckoutActivity (has extras) }
2020-12-11 12:41:44.973 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@caeac92
2020-12-11 12:41:46.821 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:192980362 intent:Intent { cmp=com.viasdigitales.fp/com.mercadopago.PaymentVaultActivity (has extras) }
2020-12-11 12:41:46.856 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ec8724f
2020-12-11 12:41:46.962 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:192980504 intent:Intent { cmp=com.viasdigitales.fp/com.mercadopago.PaymentVaultActivity (has extras) }
2020-12-11 12:41:47.091 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@a7c2b04
2020-12-11 12:41:49.002 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:192982543 intent:Intent { cmp=com.viasdigitales.fp/com.mercadopago.CardVaultActivity (has extras) }
2020-12-11 12:41:49.032 6792-6792/com.viasdigitales.fp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@7d766d7
2020-12-11 12:41:49.083 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:192982625 intent:Intent { cmp=com.viasdigitales.fp/com.mercadopago.GuessingCardActivity (has extras) }
2020-12-11 12:41:49.216 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@64a891d
2020-12-11 12:41:49.246 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
2020-12-11 12:41:49.624 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 13936 bytes, containing 1 windows, 52 views
2020-12-11 12:42:03.952 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
2020-12-11 12:42:03.953 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
2020-12-11 12:42:03.954 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
2020-12-11 12:42:24.923 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 15176 bytes, containing 1 windows, 56 views
2020-12-11 12:42:28.290 6792-6804/com.vd.fp I/es.fp: Background concurrent copying GC freed 32355(1903KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5MB/11MB, paused 574us total 103.135ms
2020-12-11 12:42:28.653 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 15212 bytes, containing 1 windows, 56 views
2020-12-11 12:42:30.661 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 15512 bytes, containing 1 windows, 57 views
2020-12-11 12:42:35.679 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:193029221 intent:Intent { cmp=com.viasdigitales.fp/com.mercadopago.InstallmentsActivity (has extras) }
2020-12-11 12:42:35.761 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3bc06c
2020-12-11 12:42:36.022 6792-6792/com.vd.fp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:193029563 intent:Intent { cmp=com.viasdigitales.fp/com.mercadopago.ReviewAndConfirmActivity (has extras) }
2020-12-11 12:42:36.108 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@e217b91
2020-12-11 12:42:51.952 6792-6792/com.vd.fp W/Choreographer: OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip!

Comment: no puedo agregar el codigo que tengo ni las fotos, nose bien porque, soy nuevo pulicando aca..

Comment: ¿Porqué no puedes agregar el código? Al igual que has escrito el texto de tu pregunta, podrías haber copiado y pegado el código como texto. Sino tu pregunta terminará cerrada sin respuesta porque a saber lo que te puede estar pasando. Puedes pulsar en _editar_ y modificar tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya probaste a usar los scratchs de tipo http que tiene el ide para descartar problemas con la conectividad?

Comment: @SuperG280 ahí quedo editada

Comment: Te sugiero revises el LogCat, incluso imprime un posible error aquí : catch (IOException e) {} cambiando a : catch (IOException e) {  e.printStackTrace(); } de esa forma se podría saber cual es el problema de forma rápida.

Comment: @Jorgesys si, revise el LogCat pero no me da error, y no creo que me de un error en ese catch ya que la ultima funcion que ejecuta es startMercadoPagoCheckout(), donde se abre mercadopago

Comment: ok si no da error que obtienes en respuesta? esta infomación es importante al formular tu pregunta.

Comment: @Jorgesys ahi subi el logcat, no me da ningun error, nose porque no lo pega como codigo

Comment: Si alguien me puede dar una mano por favot